# Поиск элемента словаря по внешнему списку

Tags: python, list, словари, dict

Есть несколько словарей следующей структуры:

```
dic1 = {'title':'Ulitsa Sezam', 'ok.ru': [0, 0], 'vk.com': [0, 0]}
dic2 = {'title':'TMNT', 'ok.ru': [0, 0], 'vk.com': [0, 0]}
```

Есть список таких словарей

```
list_of_dics = [dic1, dic2]
```

Есть отдельный список тайтлов:

```
titles_for_search = ['TMNT', 'Ulitsa Sezam' 'Starwars']
```

Как мне обратиться к элементам вложенного словаря, зная элемент список тайтла, через list_of_dics? Например, я хочу поменять первую цифру у vk.com для словаря, у которого выполняется условие:

```
'titile' == titles_for_search[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dic1 = {'title':'Ulitsa Sezam', 'ok.ru': [0, 0], 'vk.com': [0, 0]}
dic2 = {'title':'TMNT', 'ok.ru': [0, 0], 'vk.com': [0, 0]}

list_of_dics = [dic1, dic2]
titles_for_search = ['TMNT', 'Ulitsa Sezam' 'Starwars']


# Создаёте словарь словарей с title в качестве ключей
indexed = {dic['title']: dic for dic in list_of_dics}

# Теперь в нём можете найти нужный словарь по его title
print(
    indexed[titles_for_search[0]]
)

# И меняйте в нём всё, что нужно
indexed[titles_for_search[0]]['vk.com'][0] = 1

print(
    indexed[titles_for_search[0]]
)
```

Но, вообще, я бы посоветовал вам поизучать классы. Когда в коде появляются такие многоуровневые обращения к элементам, это звоночек, что от хаоса вложенных контейнеров стоит уходить.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо! Да, про ООП знаю, но просто не представляю как написать подобное в режиме ООП. Можете дать, пожалуйста, наводку в плане статей, где нечто подобное реализовывалось через классы? Или хотя бы по каким запросам искать?

Comment: Ну, суть в том, что каждый отдельный словарь заменяете на объект класса, для которого реализуете методы с понятными названиями, чтобы не громоздить многоэтажные гусеницы из квадратных скобок.

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня эти словаря генерятся автоматом. Автоматическую генерацию возможно предусмотреть на объекты класса?

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_dics[0]["vk.com"][0] = 1
print(list_of_dics[0]["vk.com"])
```

[1, 0]

Comment: А если я не знаю порядковый номер элемента list_of_dics? Это здесь очевидно, а когда список намного больше, то порядковый номер не известен, соответственно list_of_dics[0] - не совсем подходит